# Validate XML before FOP Transform

Tags: xml, apache-fop

I want to validate the XML output from my XMLReader against an XML Schema, before running a FOP transform on it.

I can do the two steps independently, but this means that the XMLReader is processed twice. I can't see how to use the output from the Validator and feed it back into the transform.

The code I am running is below.

Thanks for any help

the source:

```
Source src = new SAXSource(myXMLReader, myInputSource);
```

the validation:

```
URL schemaUrl = this.getClass().getResource("/myschema.xsd");
String schemaLang = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
SchemaFactory jaxp = SchemaFactory.newInstance(schemaLang);
Schema schema = jaxp.newSchema(schemaUrl);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

validator.validate(src);
```

the transform:

```
Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/MyTemplate.xslt")));

Result fopResult = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
transformer.transform(src, fopResult);
```

Comment: "XMLReader is processed twice" <-- how so? It's only processed when you first assign a value to `Source src`, isn't it?

Comment: Apparently not - I have some LOG statements in my XMLReader, and they are output twice if I call validator.validate as well as transformer.transform

Comment: Could you share those log statements with us?